# compare two object and log values that do not exist with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to compare two objects with the purpose of logging out the ones which do not exist in the first object.

First Object

```
this.Object1 =[{id:1, name,'Coke'}, {id:2, name,Fanta},{id:3, name,'Sprite'}, {id:4, name,'Pepsi'}]
```

Second Object

```
this.Object 2 = [{id:1, name,'Coke'}, {id:2, name,'Fanta'},{id:5, name,'Miranda'}, {id:6, name,'Alvaro', id:7, 'Orange Juice'}]
```

What I want to achieve is to loop through `object1` and find their `ids` that don't exist in `object2` and push those in there

so the final result of `object1` will be like this

```
[{id:1, name,'Coke'}, {id:2, name,Fanta},{id:3, name,'Sprite'}, {id:4, name,'Pepsi',id:5, name,'Miranda'}, {id:6, name,'Alvaro', id:7, 'Orange Juice'}]
```

Script

```
for (let r = 0; r < this.object1.length; r++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.object2.length; i++) {
      if (this.object1.id != this.object2[i].id) {
      this.object2.push(this.object1[r]);
      console.log(this.object1[i].name  + ' does not exist');
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? it may help you

```js
obj1 = [{id:1, name:'Coke'}, {id:2, name: 'Fanta'},{id:3, name: 'Sprite'}, {id:4, name:'Pepsi'}]
obj2 = [{id:1, name:'Coke'}, {id:2, name:'Fanta'},{id:5, name:'Miranda'}, {id:6, name:'Alvaro'},{ id:7, name: 'Orange Juice'}]
ids = []
obj1.map(res => {ids.push(res.id)})
obj2.map(res => {
    if(!ids.includes(res.id)){
        obj1.push(res)
    }
})
// [ { id: 1, name: 'Coke' }, { id: 2, name: 'Fanta' }, { id: 3, name: 'Sprite' }, { id: 4, name: 'Pepsi' }, { id: 5, name: 'Miranda' }, { id: 6, name: 'Alvaro' }, { id: 7, name: 'Orange Juice' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
var o = [{id:1, name:'Coke'}, {id:2, name:'Fanta'},{id:3, name:'Sprite'}, {id:4, name:'Pepsi'}];
var oo= [{id:1, name:'Coke'}, {id:5, name:'ZZZ'}, {id:6, name:'YYY'}, {id:9, name:'XXX'}, {id:4, name:'Pepsi'}];

var unique = oo.filter(x=>o.findIndex(y=>y.id===x.id)===-1);

console.log(unique);
var all = o.concat(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues/tyops in your objects. `{id:3, name,'Sprite'}`needs to be `{id:3, name: 'Sprite'}` for example. When this is fixed you can write something like this if using es6:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id:1, name:'Coke'},
  {id:2, name: 'Fanta'},
  {id:3, name: 'Sprite'},
  {id:4, name: 'Pepsi'}
]

const arr2 = [
  {id:1, name: 'Coke'}, 
  {id:2, name: 'Fanta'},
  {id:5, name: 'Miranda'}, 
  {id:6, name: 'Alvaro'},
  {id:7, name: 'Orange Juice'},
]

const getIds = (arr) => arr.map(i => i.id)

const diff = getIds(arr2).filter((item) => getIds(arr1).includes(item))

console.log('Diff:', diff)
```